# Flutter crop photo to fixed size

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

In Flutter, I want to fit the photo added by the user in 1024x768 dimensions, so that the user can only zoom in or out according to the given size (1024x768). Is there a suitable package for this?

Comment: InteractiveViewer ? maybe